# Recieving Data from webpage using the HttpListener

Tags: c#, html

I'm running into a small problem. I'm currently working on a program that has to receive data from a webpage when a form is submitted,

So what I want to do is: when the user pressed the submit button on the webpage, the C# program should pick it up and show it in the console.

How can I accomplish this because I can't get any further?

I've found a lot of examples but none seem to work.
The is the example that I used:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/599978/An-HttpListener-Server-for-Handling-AJAX-POST-Re

Then we have our code.

**C# Code**

```
    public static void StartListening()
    {        

        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        SetPrefixes(listener);

        if (listener.Prefixes.Count > 0)
        {
            listener.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("HttpClient Started");  

            while(true)
            {
                HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
                HttpListenerRequest request= context.Request;
                HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

// this is were i included the SetContent()
                string html = Properties.Resources.index;
                byte[] webPageBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);

                response.ContentLength64 = webPageBuffer.Length;
                Stream ouputStream = response.OutputStream;
                ouputStream.Write(webPageBuffer, 0, webPageBuffer.Length);

                ouputStream.Flush();

                Common.Wait(2000);  

                String url = request.RawUrl;
                String[] queryStringArray = url.Split('/');
                String postedtext = GetPostedText(request);


                byte[] buffer = null;

                // Lots of if statements because a switch would not work here.
                if(queryStringArray[0] == "myForm")
                {
                    buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("I recieved myForm");
                }
                if(queryStringArray[1] == "doSomething")
                {
                    buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("I recieved doSomething");
                }
                if(buffer != null)
                {
                    response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                    response.AddHeader("Acces-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
                    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
                    Stream secondStream = response.OutputStream;                       
                    secondStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    secondStream.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void SetPrefixes(HttpListener listener)
    {
        String[] prefixes = new String[] { "http://localhost:8000/", "http://192.168.33.28:8000/" };

        int i = 0;

        foreach (string s in prefixes)
        {
            listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
            i++;
        }
    }


    private static string GetPostedText(HttpListenerRequest request)
    {
        string recievedText;

        using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream, request.ContentEncoding))
        {
            recievedText= reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        if (recievedText != "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} RECIEVED: " + recievedText, DateTime.Now);
        }

        return recievedText;
    }


}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<html>
<head> 
    <title>LocatieScanner</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <style>

        body{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
    }

    legend{
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 14px !important;
    }


    fieldset{
        width:200px;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-right: -50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) }

    .wrapper{
        width: 100%;
    }

    </style>


    <script language="javascript">

    //<!-- Create variable timer -->
        var timer;


    //<!-- Create Fucntion CheckOne -->
    /* 
        Wannneer de functie aangroepen word, word eerst de timeout van de variable timer geleegd.
        Daarna word er een timeout ingesteld van 2000 (2sec). Die timeout wordt ingeschakeld nadat het textveld niet meer actief beschouwd word(niet meer gebruikt word, de focus blijft wel op het veld.).
        Na die 2 seconden krijgt de volgende textbox de focus met de zelfde manier maar onder een andere functie.
        Zodra hier ook de 2 seconden om zijn verspringt de focus weer maar nu naar een sumbit (verzenden) knop. Dit is gedaan omdat je dan makkelijk op een OK knop kan drukken op het apparaat.
    */

        function CheckOne() {
             clearTimeout(timer)
             timer = setTimeout(function(){
                 document.getElementById("two").focus();
                 //clearTimeout(timer);
             }, 750)
        }

        function CheckTwo(){
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(function(){
                 document.getElementById("sub").focus();
             }, 750)
        }


    </script> 




</head> 

<body> 

<div class="wrapper"> 
    <fieldset> 
        <legend>Locatiescanner</legend><br/> 
        <form id="searchForm" action="http://localhost:8000/myForm/doSomething" >
            Locatienummer: <br />
            <input type="text" id="one" onkeyup="CheckOne()" name="locatienummer"><br />
            Bonnummer: <br />
            <input type="text" id="two" onkeyup="CheckTwo()" name="bonnummer"><br /><br />
            <input id="sub" type="submit" value="Verzenden" />
        </form> 
    </fieldset> 
</div> 
<!-- Include the needed files--> 

    <script>
$("#searchForm").submit(function (event)
{
    // Stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get some values from elements on the page:
    var $form = $(this),

    locatieValue = $form.find("input[name='locatienummer']").val(),
    bonValue = $form.find("input[name='bonnummer']").val(),

    url = $form.attr("action");

    // Send the data using post
    $.post(url, { a: locatieValue, b: bonValue });

});
    </script>

</body> 
</html>
```

**Where I receive the error: An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection.**

```
 private static string GetPostedText(HttpListenerRequest request)
    {
        string recievedText;

        using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream, request.ContentEncoding))
        {
       Where i Get the error-->>>     recievedText= reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        if (recievedText != "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} RECIEVED: " + recievedText, DateTime.Now);
        }

        return recievedText;
    }
```

**Possible Problem**

The problem could be here

```
                String url = request.RawUrl;
                String[] queryStringArray = url.Split('/');
                String postedtext = GetPostedText(request);
```

When I go through my breakpoint I see the URL I want in the `queryStringArray` but because of the while loop it is reset every time so I cant get the data I want.

Also the `queryStringArray` isn't always the same length.

Can I get some help with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that as your html part:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.post demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="http://localhost:8000/myForm/doSomething" id="searchForm">

    Locatienummer:<input type="text" name="a" placeholder="...">
    <br />
    <br />
    Bonnummer:<input type="text" name="b" placeholder="...">

    <br />
    <br />

    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>

  <!-- the result of the search will be rendered inside this div -->
  <div id="result"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Attach a submit handler to the form

        $("#searchForm").submit(function (event)
        {
            // Stop form from submitting normally
            event.preventDefault();

            // Get some values from elements on the page:
            var $form = $(this),

            aValue = $form.find("input[name='a']").val(),
            bValue = $form.find("input[name='b']").val(),

            url = $form.attr("action");

            // Send the data using post
            $.post(url, { a: aValue, b: bValue });

        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is your HttpListener:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class Program
    {    
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(StartListening);

            thread.Start();
        }

        private static void StartListening()
        {
            HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();

            SetPrefixes(listener);

            if (listener.Prefixes.Count > 0)
            {
                listener.Start();

                while (true)
                {
                    HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
                    HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;

                    String url = request.RawUrl;
                    String[] queryStringArray = url.Split('/');

                    string postedText = GetPostedText(request);

                    HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

                    byte[] buffer = null;

                    if (queryStringArray[1] == "myForm")
                    {
                        buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("I received myForm");
                    }

                    if (queryStringArray[2] == "doSomething")
                    {
                        buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("I received doSomething");
                    }

                    if (buffer != null)
                    {
                        response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                        response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

                        response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
                        Stream outputStream = response.OutputStream;
                        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        outputStream.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void SetPrefixes(HttpListener listener)
        {
            String[] prefixes = new String[] { "http://localhost:8000/" };

            int i = 0;

            foreach (string s in prefixes)
            {
                listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
                i++;
            }
        }

        private static string GetPostedText(HttpListenerRequest request)
        {
            string text = "";

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream, request.ContentEncoding))
            {
                text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            return text;
        }
    }
}
```

You can see the text which you entered into the boxes inside postedText variable in C# side.

I hope this helps you.

EDIT:

Comment out the below lines and try again:

```
// this is were i included the SetContent()
string html = Properties.Resources.index;
byte[] webPageBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);

response.ContentLength64 = webPageBuffer.Length;
Stream ouputStream = response.OutputStream;
ouputStream.Write(webPageBuffer, 0, webPageBuffer.Length);

ouputStream.Flush();

Common.Wait(2000);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80078/discussion-on-answer-by-orkun-bekar-recieving-data-from-webpage-using-the-httpli).